# References and external class use problems

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Using Visual Studio 2015 on an ASP.NET project. Everything works fine except now I have a block of code (A common AD utility function) that I want all the pages to be able to access. The original language (inherited project) is VB.NET, but it should work just fine either way.

I created a class file, named it CommonADFunctions.vb. The file uses System.DirectoryServices, and there's a reference in the project to that assembly. However, there are two problems:

1. I can't reference the new class to call the functions from any of the page code files. This includes attempts to instantiate a new variable as the class type.
2. When I move the new .VB file into App_Code, the reference to System.DirectoryServices breaks, and it refuses to build.

This may seem like a trivial ask, but what am I missing?

Comment: is this a web site project or web application project?

Comment: To access Methods of the class you need to instantiate the class, you don't mention if you do that or not.

Comment: @IsaacKleinman, As this project file was inherited, and my experience with VS is somewhat limited, how would I tell the difference, and what difference does it make?

Comment: Did you create `public static` classes in the external file?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to use code from another project, that may be based on older dependencies. You would need to either resolve those dependencies, or come up with some other solution, like create a compiled DLL and reference it that way.

Comment: Also, if you're inheriting a project, you should still know what instantiate means.

Comment: Of course I know what instantiate means, The complaint is that I couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was a simple property on the file itself I created a new Class File, and somehow the Build Action got set to Content rather than Compile. Setting this to Compile allowed the object to be referenced and instantiated properly. It doesn't fix the IDE intelliSense from APP_Code for DirectoryServices references in the code, but it compiles and runs, which is what I needed.

EDIT: Received external help which pointed this out.

Answer (score 0):

Without code and screenshots to illustrate I can only recommend a few things to try.

> I can't reference the new class to call the functions from any of the page code files. This includes attempts to instantiate a new variable as the class type.

1. The methods in the class have `Private` or `Friend` scope.
2. Its a `static` class (a Module in VB.Net) and you do not need to instantiate it.
3. You are somehow referencing an old DLL which doesn't have the methods. Check the reference to this AD project and make sure its "Referenced" via Project.

> When I move the new .VB file into App_Code, the reference to System.DirectoryServices breaks, and it refuses to build.

This sounds like a corrupt project file. Clean the solution, delete the .suo file, delete the obj & bin folders.

Then move the CommonADFunctions.vb to the App_Code folder and add the DLL reference to System.DirectoryServices. Or create the CommonADFunctions.vb file in App_Code to start with.